# debugging node.js child_process fork example on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, child-process

I am trying to debug the child_process [example from here](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle) using [IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and [node 10.10](http://nodejs.org/). When I run `nodejs app.js` from a terminal everything works. The console output displays as expected. However, when I debug the same script using IDEA there are no messages in console output and the app just sits there. This is what is in the console window:

```
/usr/bin/nodejs --debug-brk=58954 app.js
debugger listening on port 58954
debugger listening on port 58954
```

When I **run** the script in IDEA without the debugger attached, the script works as expected.

Why does attaching the debugger break the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a bug in node.js fork to me: both parent and child processes receive `--debug-brk=58954` switch and attempt to start debugger and listen port 58954.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the children to use a free port for debugging. InteliJ will automatically pick up the port chosen by the child process.

Here's an example:

```
// Determine if in debug mode. 
// If so, pass in a debug-brk option manually, without specifying port.
var startOpts = {};
var isInDebugMode = typeof v8debug === 'object';
if(isInDebugMode) {
     startOpts = {execArgv: ['--debug-brk']};
}
child_process.fork('./some_module.js', startArgs, startOpts);
```

Comment: in my case, I didn't want to debug the child process, but I wanted debugging in my parent process to work, so I just always pass `{ execArgv: [] }` into my fork call. Thanks for the heads up!